# Access 2013 Runtime - Some weird issues (Form doesn't show up at one computer but doesn't on another)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Lately I am having some very weird problems and I can't exactly pin out what is causing it.

I've got an Access frontend application which uses SQL Server linked tables. A few days ago I deployed a new ACCDE version which caused some very weird problems.

At one computer I was unable to open a form from the Ribbon (some 21~ ish error can't exactly remember but it was a default open-form error). After some investigation I found out that the problem is caused by an `allow additions = false` line on the `on-open event` of the form. This however is very strange since it has always been there. Besides that, at almost every other computer, including mine, it just works fine while the code (and forms, queries, etc.) are exactly the same..

When trying to open the same access file in accdb at that specific computer it does seem to work (opening being done with runtime version). 
So as workaround (for the time being) we made sure that that this computer opened the file as accdb while the others (where it did work) opened it as accdde.

Today however it went wrong again but on a different computer and a different issue. Now a completely other form doesn't load it's data (it's empty). Testing it locally it works fine however and testing it yet again on another computer (with also a runtime version) it also opens fine with data in it...

The weird thing is when using an older file (a few application versions back) just works fine but the current one doesn't, at least not on all computers. This makes me believe that the file is corrupted but the weird thing is, why DOES it work on some other computers? If the file would be corrupted you would say that it is causing the issues on all the computers?

So the next thing I thought of was different Access runtime versions. I tested 4 computers (two where everything works fine) and the other 2 have issues.

- Computer one (which works fine) is a 32 bit system with Access runtime version 15.0.4841
- Computer two (with issues) is a 64 bit system with Access runtime version 15.0.4569
- Computer three (also with issues) is a 32 bit system with Access runtime version 15.0.4833
- Computer four (my own computer tested against a local db) is a 64 bit system with Access runtime version 15.0.4849

So the computers where the Access file doesn't work all have a lower version than the ones that do work, is it possible that this is causing the problem?? If it is, I still wonder why the older Access application file works on all computers but the current one doesn't..

On a side note:

- Also tried to repair the access runtime version on one of the computer where it didn't worked but this had no effect
- Doing a Compact & repair on the Access file itself also doesn't have any effect

Comment: Try to save problemaic form under new name, delete "bad" one and rename copy to original name. Sometimes it repairs wierd errors. Make sure that Track Name Autocorrect switched off. The problem appears on accde only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you plain and simple cannot run an x32 accDE database with the x64 bit runtime – it simply will not work.

And if the runtime versions are different on those target machines then you want to un-install the runtime, and download the latest version. Windows update will NOT update the runtime. With runtime 2010, you had to download + install runtime, and then ALSO download an update to the runtime.

With 2013, then the latest download of the runtime will always include the latest SP updates.

Attempting to run Access with different runtimes will in general be a disaster. And in the case of attempting to use the x64 bit runtime on an application compiled to x32 will not work at all.

I would also before you compile to an accDE check and remove any and all references not required. So references to word, excel or anything else should be removed and late binding should be used.

Regardless, you want to ensure that all computers are using the same runtime version, and this includes the bit size. So in all cases you want to ensure and use the x32 bit runtime, and then ensure that all machines are running the same version/revision of the runtime.

Comment: I think he means Windows 64bit, not Access runtime 64bit. But yes, using the exact same Access version everywhere is a must.

Comment: All clear but one question remains, when downloading the latest runtime version, the version number of Access seems to be older than some others (two windows 7 computers also have different Access versions). Does this mean I need to run windows updates to get it to the same version?

Comment: Windows update DOES NOT touch the runtime. You have to un-install and then re-download and then re-install. You likely best download your OWN copy, and then supply that to your client base. That way windows update will NEVER bite you or bother you. Only problem is those machines that have full edition of office/Access since runtime installer is IGNORED. The result is that windows update WILL UPDATE those with full editions of ms-access. However those with only runtime will NOT receive updates to Access. (so you wind up with a mix if some users are using full edition of Access).

Comment: So windows update will update those machines with full edition of Access - that's how those machines changed on you.